# Git Gui - how to push to production?

Tags: git, git-push, git-gui

I am using Git Gui.

I have pushed my changes to master.

But in order to make them live they have to be pushed to `master:production`.

I don't see any options for **production** when I click the push button. The only thing that appears in the Source Branches is **master**.

Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to pull the code into production?

Comment: I've made a clone of the server files locally, edited them, and would like to push the edits to live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in Git Gui to select another remote branch for push, you have to do it from the command line:

```
git push remote local_branch:remote_branch
```

So in your case this is

```
git push remote master:production
```